# How to find the sum of each part in a list in pyrhon?

Tags: python, list

The task we are supposed to do is look at a list like

```
[3884, 2888, 2752, 3916, 1479, 2455]
```

These numbers are meant to symbolize barcodes.
Then 2 parameters are given for which part of the list to look at.

For example, the parameters are `(list,1,3)`. Where 1 and 3 is the part of the list we need to use. We then have to find the sum of each part of the list. We need to be able to output `[26,16, 19]`. The last part is finding the max number and returning the original barcode. For that, I plan to use `if & elif` statements because `max` is not allowed. I need help in finding the sum of each part of the list.

```
def freshFruit (barcodes, startIndex, stopIndex):
    barcodesTested= barcodes[startIndex:int(stopIndex)+1:])# +1 make it inclusive
    print (barcodesTested)
    numberInList = len(barcodesTested)
    print(numberInList)
    x=0
    for x in range(len(barecodesTested)):#i was thinking of find each sum individually
     for barecodesTested[x] in:
```

Comment: First convert each element to a string, then enumerate each character of the string, converting back to an integer, and perform the sums.

Comment: Do you know how to get the sum of digits for a *single* number?

Comment: The `max` function will not help you here anyway.

Comment: No, I do not know how to get the sum of a digit for a single number

Answer (score 4):

You can use list-comprehension. Iterate each number in the list, then convert it to string, now iterate each digit in this converted string and convert each digit to integer, finally calculate the `sum`

```py
data = [5789, 3795, 1349, 4839, 3829, 9267]

[sum(int(i) for i in str(each)) for each in data]

#output
[29, 24, 17, 24, 22, 24]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try defining a function to sum all the digits in an integer, using the [`%`](https://realpython.com/python-modulo-operator/) and [`//`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/floor_division.html) operators:

```
def sum_digits(num):
    s = 0
    while num:
        s += num % 10
        num //= 10
    return s

nums = [5789, 3795, 1349, 4839, 3829, 9267]
print(list(map(sum_digits, nums)))
```

Output:

```
[29, 24, 17, 24, 22, 24]
```

Note that although converting the integers to strings and back to integers may use less code, it is widely considered a bad practice.

Comment: Thank you for helping. Do you mind explaining how this works cause I tried to code trace it and I am so lost.

Comment: The `num % 10` returns the last digit of `num`, and `num //= 10` gets rid of the last digit of `num`. `while num:` will keep looping until `num` reaches `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Make each digit of a number an int. Find sum.

```
newList = [sum(map(int,str(num))) for num in x]
```

Questions that show no effort to answer themselves, will receive no answering effort.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering my question I appreciate the help. What do you mean by "Questions that show no effort to answer themselves, will receive no answering effort."  I tried to be as clear as possible in asking my question.

Comment: Alot of people where not able to understand what you where asking thus it was closed. It's best to add as much information as you can. One big part is to show what you have tried. Stackoverflow is not a place to get code written for you.

Comment: And yes, there is a section, https://imgur.com/S8zQVeH